# how does a vnc server 'service' get around Session 0 isolation (no desktop interaction) in windows 7?

Tags: session, windows-7, service, desktop, vnc

I'm wondering if there is a windows API that gets called or are the developers just wizards? cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old, but figured I would post a reply in case anyone was still interested. I followed a method very similar to this to have a service launch an application on the desktop. http://www.developerfusion.com/community/blog-entry/8389765/creating-a-process-in-another-user-session/

You may want to also call LoadUserProfile prior to launching the process.